# Adding Headers to a created CSV file in Ruby - keep getting errors

Tags: ruby, json, csv, hash

I've been trying to use Ruby to create a CSV file from json data. I was able to create the file, but I need to add a few headers. I tried following suggestions and answers from similar questions posted here on Stack Overflow, but I keep getting errors. Can anyone give me some pointers?

Here's my code.

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

CSV.open("your_csv.csv", "w") do |csv| 
  JSON.parse(File.open("tojson.txt").read).each do |hash| 
    csv << hash.values 
    @csv.each { |line| line['New_header'] = line[0].to_i + line[1].to_i }
    end
end
```

And here is the error I'm getting:
[image: error]

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't use images for data, errors or code. We can't copy/paste that information forcing us to type it in.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you add headers to a csv file. When you generate csv content, a header row is just a regular row. And should be generated as such. Example:

```
CSV.open("your_csv.csv", "w") do |csv| 
  csv << ['new_header', 'value1', 'value2'] # the headers
  JSON.parse(File.open("tojson.txt").read).each do |hash| 
    row = [generate, values, for, headers, above]
    csv << row
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, you can also do `CSV.open("foo.csv", "w", headers: arr, write_headers: true)`.

Comment: @Jordan: hm, never used this form before. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `@csv` variable. You have a `csv` one.